# AsyncTask pause and resume

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a activity that show one listview. In the activity I have a one AsyncTask (named here of AsListView) to get values from internet and fill some informations in each item of the listview. Work fine.

Now I created a button in ActionBar to show one image from streetview. To do this I have implemented another AsyncTask (named here of AsImage) to get image from google and show in a DialogFragment, but is necessary wait the execution of all AsListView Threads. It spends long time depending of the number of items in the list.

To execute AsImage rapidily, I cancel all AsListView tasks, but it's not good for me (user loss informations). The ideal soluction is set AsListView tasks to wait while AsImage execute. When AsImage finish I set AsListView tasks to continue execution. But I know that is not possible handle the control of execution  of AsynkTasks.....

Some solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to synchronize the `AsyncTask`s using a [`CountDownLatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Otherwise if you want you can use `Thread`s instead of `AsyncTask`s and set their priorities, but there is a reason android made the `AsyncTask` class so I recommend you use it.